# Accessing nested STL structures and size calls

Tags: c++, stl

So I have a constructor which looks like
HNS::HNS
     vector>> storage(1000, vector >(1000));

I also have a function to insert elements, that looks like

```
void HNS::insert(const string& host, const int& ip) {
   hash<HostName> hash;
   auto resultno = hash(host);
   auto result = resultno%size; 
   cout << "size of current container is : " << (storage.at(result)).size() << endl;

   storage.at(result).emplace_back(host, ip);
}
```

However, the emplace_back and cout calls gives me out of range exceptions when running it. 
In the constructor, I can print storage.at(600).size() fine, but in the insert function, the cout and the emplace calls fail. Any idea why this is?

Regards

Comment: *the emplace_back function, while compiling, gives me a out of range exception when running it* What?

Comment: I think it is because I haven't defined storage properly. It needs to be global. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: @enrm `resultno%size` Where did `size` come from in the code you posted?

Comment: I added these definitions:  `typedef string HostName;
typedef int IPAddress;
int size=1000;` so I could compile it; and it compiled and ran without complaint.  Maybe if you posted a complete example?  ("Short, self-contained," but not correct, of course!)

Comment: Yes sorry, I was a bit quick to jump the gun when I was posting. You are correct in your assumptions, hostname and ipaddress are aliases i used. size is the initial size of the vector, defined globally.

The issue was solved when I realized that in the constructor, the storage variable was initialized and worked correctly, but had another reference to itself in the insert method (?) I solved it by making a temp storage and assigning storage = temp to define storage in the scope of the entire class. 

This could probably have been done better, but I digress..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your error, but the code you did post has flaws,  enough so that an out-of-range exception could occur.

Your code is faulty in that it never checks if `result` is in range.  You also don't check if `storage` is empty (a vector can be cleared very easily, so your declaration doesn't show us what may have happened before your code is executed).

A safer implementation would look like this:

```
void HNS::insert(const HostName& host, const IPAddress& ip) 
{
   if ( storage.empty() )
       return;

   hash<HostName> hash;
   auto resultno = hash(host);
   auto result = resultno % size; 
   result = std::min(result, storage.size() - 1);
   cout << "size of current container is : " << (storage.at(result)).size() << endl;
   storage.at(result).emplace_back(host, ip);
}
```

Now you're guaranteed that `result` will not be out of range.